# I need to reshape matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 x 16 matrix. And I have 1000 of them.
Currently, they are stored as 1000 x 4 x 16. 
However, I would like to first transpose the matrix. (16 x 4). And then put them onto 1000 rows.

1000 x 16 x 4.

How should I reshape my 1000 x 4 x 16 using numpy or any other method in python.

Comment: Are we talking numpy?

Comment: sure. Yes, i want to do with numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numpy.swapaxes(3Dmatrix, 1, 2)
```

should do the trick

Comment: Nice! Was not aware of this function!

Comment: I'd use `3Dmatrix.transpose(0,2,1)`, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: I find swapaxes as easy to work with if you have small number of dimensions (less than 4) and easier to work work with when you have high dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
np.swapaxes(your_matrix, 1, 2)
```

See [the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html)

Answer (score 1):

your input:

```
>>> test = np.vstack([ np.zeros((1,3,4)), np.ones((1,3,4))])
>>> test[0]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

>>> test[1]
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

your output:

```
>>> new_test = np.vstack([m.T[None,:,:] for m in test])
>>> new_test[0]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

>>> new_test[1]
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```